# XML (and maybe other) File paths with special characters error using R > 3.5.0

Tags: r, xml, filepath

I am facing some problems reading XML files which file paths contains special characters. Speciffically file paths with spanish words with accents

Other files, such as CSV, TXT or XLSX can be accesed.

I am using RStudio and R 3.6.0.

A workaround is to use R 3.4.0. I think with 3.5.0 enconding was changed to UTF-8 and since then some packages faces this filepaths issues.

I would like if possible a solution that enables to use the latest version of R without changing the packages to read XML in this case (XML).

A prepared repo for reproducible error is available at:
https://github.com/AlvaroPica/file_paths_in_R

```r
library(XML)
library(readr)

full_dirpath_wrong = "C:/Users/alvaro.picatoste/workspace/error/fóo_accent/"
full_dirpath_good = "C:/Users/alvaro.picatoste/workspace/error/foo_no_accent/"

rel_dirpath_wrong = "./fóo_accent/"
rel_dirpath_good = "./foo_no_accent/"

use_full = TRUE

if (use_full == TRUE) {
  dirpath_wrong <- full_dirpath_wrong
  dirpath_good <- full_dirpath_good
} else {
  dirpath_wrong <- rel_dirpath_wrong
  dirpath_good <- rel_dirpath_good
}

xml_fname = "pipas.xml"
xml_fpath_wrong = file.path(dirpath_wrong, xml_fname)
xml_fpath_good= file.path(dirpath_good, xml_fname)

csv_fname = "pipas.csv"  
csv_fpath_wrong= file.path(dirpath_wrong, csv_fname)
csv_fpath_good=file.path(dirpath_good, csv_fname)

txt_fname = "pipas.txt"
txt_fpath_wrong=file.path(dirpath_wrong, txt_fname)
txt_fpath_good=file.path(dirpath_good, txt_fname)

xlsx_fname = "pipas.xlsx"
xlsx_fpath_wrong=file.path(dirpath_wrong, xlsx_fname)
xlsx_fpath_good=file.path(dirpath_good, xlsx_fname)

my_good_xml <- xmlParse(xml_fpath_good)
my_good_csv <- read.csv(csv_fpath_good)
my_good_txt <- readLines(txt_fpath_good, n=1, warn=FALSE)
my_good_xlsx <- readxl::read_excel(xlsx_fpath_good)

my_wrong_xml <- xmlParse(xml_fpath_wrong)
my_wrong_csv <- read.csv(csv_fpath_wrong)
my_wrong_txt <- readLines(txt_fpath_wrong, n=1, warn=FALSE)
my_wrong_xlsx <- readxl::read_excel(xlsx_fpath_wrong)
```

This is the actual file_path:
"C:/Users/alvaro.picatoste/workspace/error/fóo_accent/pipas.xml"

And this is the error I got when reading XML but not other files:

```
Error in xmlParse(xml_fpath_wrong) : 
  Can't find file C:/Users/alvaro.picatoste/workspace/error/fÃ³o_accent//pipas.xml
```

With txt, csv and xlsx and corresponding packages I did not face this problem.

Is there any solution that help me reading the XML without modiying the way I read them?

Comment: Your *my_wrong_xml* attempt is the first line above all other *wrong* extensions. Does code successfully render with subsequent lines: *my_wrong_csv*, *my_wrong_txt*, *my_wrong_xlsx*?

Comment: Yeah, the do, sorry I did not specified. They all read the files